# Как решить: не могу передать русские символы через QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, кодировка

Не получается передать на QTcpServer русские символы используя QTcpSocket::write().
Если вывожу на сервере просто в qinfo, то получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вместо

```
"client:fin:терапевт:"
```

Если же использую QString::fromUtf8(), то просто получаю знаки вопроса. 
(обычные, в квадратиках)

client:

```
QString msg = "client:fin:" + qualification + ":";
_socket.write(msg.toUtf8());
```

server:

```
   QTcpSocket *clientSocket = static_cast<QTcpSocket *>(sender());
    socket_descriptor id_user_socs = clientSocket->socketDescriptor();

    QByteArray msg = clientSocket->readAll();

    qInfo() << msg;
```

Comment: Кодировка источника и приёмника должны совпадать. Не понятно каким образом и куда идет вывод данных. Покажите как именно вы выводите данные на экран.

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо за помощь. Я уже разобрался, всё-таки это проблема с qinfo. А инфа, после того как я начал предварительно использовать QString::toUtf8() перед отправкой и QString::fromUtf8() после получения, начала считываться нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, всё-таки это проблема с qinfo, он плохо выводит.

А инфа, после того как я начал предварительно использовать QString::toUtf8() перед отправкой и QString::fromUtf8() после получения, начала считываться нормально.